# rsyslog , collect log from files outside /var/log

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have different logs that are written to our moutend nfs share that i need to send to our syslog-server (graylog) they are located outside /var/log folder.
So i add some extra conf in /etc/rsyslog.d/
For this example i have two files with following config:

**atlassian-application-confluence-log.conf**

```
module(load="imfile")
module(load="imklog")
$MaxMessageSize 50k
global(workDirectory="/atlassian/test/confluence/logs")

# This is the main application log file
input(type="imfile"
File="/atlassian/test/confluence/logs/atlassian-confluence.log"
Tag="atlassian"
PersistStateInterval="200"
)

# This file contains entries related to the search index.
input(type="imfile"
File="/atlassian/test/confluence/logs/atlassian-confluence-index.log"
Tag="atlassian"
PersistStateInterval="200"
)

# Send to Graylog
action(type="omfwd" target="log-server-company.com" port="5140")

# if you want to keep a local copy of the logs.
action(type="omfile" File="/var/log/rsyslog.log" template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

**atlassian-application-jira-log.conf**

```
module(load="imfile")
module(load="imklog")
$MaxMessageSize 50k

global(workDirectory="/atlassian/test/jira/log")

# Contains logging for most of Jira, including logs that aren’t specifically written elsewhere
input(type="imfile"
File="/atlassian/test/jira/log/atlassian-jira.log"
Tag="atlassian"
PersistStateInterval="200"
)

# Send to Graylog
action(type="omfwd" target="log-server-company.com" port="5140")

# if you want to keep a local copy of the logs.
action(type="omfile" File="/var/log/rsyslog.log" template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

So to my problem.
When i check the Rsyslogd configuration with following command:
**rsyslogd -N1 -f /etc/rsyslog.d/atlassian-application-confluence-log.conf**
It says it is valid. 
When i restart the rsyslog service i get the following errors:

```
module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
module 'imklog' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]

error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/atlassian-tomcat-confluence-log.conf, on or before line 6: parameter 'workdirectory' specified more than once - one instance is ignored. Fix config [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207]>
error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/atlassian-tomcat-confluence-log.conf, on or before line 6: parameter 'workDirectory' not known -- typo in config file? [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207] 

module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
module 'imklog' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
[origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0-10.el8" x-pid="379288" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
imjournal: journal files changed, reloading...  [v8.2102.0-10.el8 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

How can i get rid of the warnings?
I have already tried to put the two modules in /etc/rsyslog.conf

I get following errors from that config:
**parameter 'PersistStateInterval' not known
parameter 'Tag' not known
parameter 'File' not known**

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple configuration files, they are processed in ascending sort order of the file name (numerically/alphabetically), See: [$IncludeConfig](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/global/options/rsconf1_includeconfig.html).

Therefore you don't have to include any configuration parameters (modules, work directories, rulesets etc.) multiple times. You can include them once in the config which is loaded first.

Comment: Even if i declared the modules in global. 
After restarting rsyslog i get following error:
'PersistStateInterval' not known
'Tag' not known
File' not known 

It´s like it is ignoring the global rsyslog.conf file . 

It should include my conf file from rsyslog.d/ folder. 
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/                                                                                                                                                                          include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

Comment: The `input()` looks fine to me. Have you resolved the other errors? As I'm guessing this error may be caused by loading the `imfile` module multiple times - as I've seen the same happening when loading other modules multiple times. Also, I don't know how `mode` reacts in your `include()`, I thought this works only when referencing a specific file (static).

Comment: No there are still errors from the output av service rsyslog status, but the logs come in correct.

Comment: Great, one step closer! Please share your current config as well as the exact status output - without that I can only assume. You may want to create a new question, as it seems they're different and therefore require different solutions/answers.